# Border between ValueObjects and Primitives - DDD and Clean Architecture

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, domain-driven-design

I am confused where is the border between ValueObjects and Primitive types.
Should Application services takes as arguments ValueObjects or primitive types?
Same in communication between Infrastructure adapters from Application services:
For e.g.:

Application Service/CQRS layer (Examples in kotlin - Spring boot application)

```
data class RegisterNewUserCommand(
    val username: String,
    val rawPassword: String,
    val email: String)
```

or

```
data class RegisterNewUserCommand(
    val username: Username,
    val rawPassword: RawPassword,
    val email: Email)
```

and Application Ports to communicate with Infrastructure Layer:

```
interface CouponsRepository {
    fun findByCode(couponCode: CouponCode): Coupon?
}
```

or

```
interface CouponsRepository {
    fun findByCode(couponCode: String): Coupon?
}
```

I tried to find some examples of code but there are no clear answer for my problem.
Final question is: Should Application (and Domain) layer operate only on ValueObjects and Entities?

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused where is the border between ValueObjects and Primitive types.

For information coming *into* the system, where the information is represented as general purpose data structures, the usual guidance is to parse that information into a fit-for-purpose data structure as early as possible.

But as early as possible is a balance of trade-offs; on the one hand the sooner we wrap the data the longer we accrue the advantages of wrapping the data, but on the other hand we're introducing coupling.

In other words, we want to think about potential re-usability of parts that are coupled to a particular domain model.

For information *leaving* the system, this is mostly about copying the information from the domain model's representation to a general purpose representation, and as a rule we don't normally need to worry about data constraints or parsing, so the advantages of the fit-for-purpose representation are reduced.

In the case of "queries", we might never see the information in its domain representation at all -- there are plenty of cases where we might take the representation provided by our persistence store and copying it into an HTTP response without ever introducing a "ValueObject".

Recommended reading:

- [Parse Don't Validate](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2019/11/05/parse-don-t-validate/)
- [At the Boundaries, Applications are not Object Oriented](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AttheBoundaries,ApplicationsareNotObject-Oriented/)